# Google Cloud Compute Engine CPU Metrick Graph Android Home Screen widget

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-play, google-compute-engine

Are there any aps that can show me my Google Cloud Compute Engine CPU usage on my home screen ?

Like this picture or something similar?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently this feature is not available. However this is a good feature idea. You can post your feedback [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.cloudconsole).